# Isometric Tilemap is blocking UI elements

Tags: unity, tilemap, isometric

I'm using Unity 2019.4.6f1, and I'm working on Isometric Tilemaps.

The hierarchy is like this:

[image: Hierarchy]

The VillageScreen is a `Canvas`, `img-bg` is an UI Image, the two `Panel`s are UI Panels, and the `Grid` and two `Tilemap`s are the isometric tilemaps. The problem is, the Grid & Tilemap is blocking all other UI elements, and it seems to be always on top, no matter how I set the Z value.

The Grid setting is:

[image: Grid Settings]

And the Panel setting is:

[image: Panel Settings]

My question is: How do I put the UI elements **ABOVE** the Tilemap?

p.s. the UI button is clickable, it just cannot be displayed properly.

--

**UPDATE:** Added a mockup screen - Black circles are buttons, while Red texts are UI texts for displaying scores.

[image: Mockup]

Comment: Why is your tilemap in your canvas? Usually this is not a component we would put into a UI Canvas like this.

Comment: @DMGregory thanks for your reply, but I would like to display the Tilemap in my game. I downloaded this completed game pack from Asset Store, and it uses various Canvas to represent different screens, instead of using separate scenes. Is it a must to use a separate Scene for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not need to place the tilemap into the canvas to achieve this effect. You can swap game objects within your scene without switching scenes - you already do this with canvasses, so there is nothing to stop you from doing it with tilemaps too.

Comment: I know I can hide & show elements. However, my issue is that the Tilemap is hiding the UI elements. Let's say I have a toolbar (as a Panel) to show ABOVE the tilemap, but Tilemap is covering all the UI elements (both panels).

Comment: I have added a mockup screen in my question for better illustrations.

Comment: I have tried Sorting Layer, Z value of Rect Transform, rearranging the hierarchy, but none solved the problem. As a last resort (I don't want to do this though), can I clip the Tilemap (like a clipping mask), so that the UI elements do not overlap the tilemap?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your Grid transform position is to `-100` on the Z-axis.  Perhaps not using the UI sorting layer for the Grid might help as well.

I'm a relative newbie in Unity so I may be wrong, but I'm doing something similar with a project I'm working on and don't have the same problem.